# Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

I got this error while migrating a table from Laravel Migration

```
Schema::create('galleries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('images');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

here is whole error coming in my terminal is:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) values (2019_11_10_143218_create_galleries_table, 2))

at /var/www/html/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
663|         catch (Exception $e) {

Exception trace:

1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value")
  /var/www/html/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

2   PDOStatement::execute()
  /var/www/html/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: The problem is not on migration. That error is when you try to insert a row. Maybe you can share with us laravel.log and, also, more lines of your code.

Comment: i only create a simple migration and run 'php artisan migrate' nothing else and i got "Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: Can you provide your full migration code? There must be something else at play here as `bigIncrements` does not require a default value as it autoincrements.

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: The actual error is, migration table 'id' field auto increments(A. I.) was turned off. Don't know how. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add a row in db not passing the id and in db table id is not set to be autogenerated.

Comment: i only create a simple migration and run 'php artisan migrate' nothing else and i got "Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: `bigIncrements` is auto incrementing and does not required a value.